# How to copy styles of a cell into another one using Google Spreadsheet API

Tags: java, styles, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to fill data to a spreadsheet using Google Spreadsheet API. What I do not understand is how can I copy styles from a row (e.g. the first one) to the cells created by my software.

I'm unable to find a way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Read/write styles** use google-apps-script, this is the only way to read and write styles that I have seen.

```
source.copyTo(ss.getRange('Sheet2!A1'), {formatOnly: true});
```

copyTo docs: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object)

**No styles in Google-spreadsheet-api:** It does not have a way to read/write styles to the sheet. I have searched for this.

**Read only** You can read the styles, by getting the sheet as HTML. Not ideal, but works.

Comment: Thanks Eddie. I have seen the link and I think it's correct. Am I wrong if I say that in order to copy only styles to the new cells I have to specify: `{ formatOnly: true }` instead of your example `{ contentsOnly: true }`?

Comment: @RobertoS. yes, you want formatOnly, I changed the example, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: But This works only within that same document, not between different sheets. I got this error,  ````"Target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet. "````