# Ho can I get data with hyperlinks and style applied in G-sheets and display using JSON url

Tags: json, angularjs, search

```
I have used below url to export the G-sheet data as a JSON feed and fetched data using gsx$topic.$t
```

// var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/153Obe1TdWlIPyveZoNxEw53rdrghHsiWU9l-WgGwCrE/1/public/values?alt=json";
    But the data is plain and no style and hyperlink data in it. how can I export the sheet to get the styles and hyperlinks.
    Is it possible to read data from published HTML url and apply filters with JSON. please suggest.

```
sample code :
<div ng-app="sample" ng-controller="sampleController">        
    <div class="black">      
        <input type="text" name="search" ng-model="search"
               placeholder="search" ng-click="didSelectLanguage()"/>          
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  <table  style="border: 1px solid black ;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><center><b>Question</b></center></td>
            <td ><center><b>Response</b></center></td>
        </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:searchFilter">
        <td style="border: 1px solid black ; width:30%;white-space: pre-wrap;">{{user.gsx$topic.$t}}</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black ; width:70%;white-space: pre-wrap;">{{user.gsx$response.$t}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('sample', []).
 controller('sampleController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {              
    var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/153Obe1TdWlIPyveZoNxEw53rdrghHsiWU9l-WgGwCrE/1/public/values?alt=json";
// var url2 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/153Obe1TdWlIPyveZoNxEw53rdrghHsiWU9l-WgGwCrE/2/public/values?alt=json";
    $http.get(url)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {     
         $scope.users = data.feed.entry;
         console.log($scope.users);
    })
    .error(function(error, status, headers, config) {
         console.log(status);
         console.log("Error occured");
    }); 
    $scope.search='';
    $scope.searchFilter=function(item){
        if(item.gsx$topic.$t.indexOf($scope.search) != -1 || item.gsx$response.$t.indexOf($scope.search) != -1){
        return true;
            }
      return false;
    }

}]);
</script>
```

Comment: But in the resource (URL) you are sharing there is no metadata related to hyperlinks and applied styles.

Comment: Yes @Danny you are right, but how we can prepare a resource URL that can include the hyperlinks and styles. can you help me, please. Similar to the publishes HTMl URL

Comment: This code by ng-bind has helped me to resolve issue. var urls = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;-]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim; if(text.match(urls)) { // to replace all url with hyperlink return $sce.trustAsHtml(text.replace(urls, "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>")); }                 Now I need help in style which is not coming through json URL

Comment: I found some links that could take you the right way:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419939/how-to-copy-styles-of-a-cell-into-another-one-using-google-spreadsheet-api and this:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet#determine_sheet_id_and_other_properties.